# Socket.Receive() | Socket.Send() | Socket.BeginXXX | Socket.XXXAsync

Tags: c#, sockets

Please bear with me if I'm missing things up, I just started exploring sockets in c# and I've came across a bunch of methods for sending/receiving data:

Besides the normal: `Send()` / `Receive()`

There is also: `xxxAsync() / BeginXxx / xxSendToXxx() / xxReceiveFromXxx()`

- What is the difference between all these methods exactly?
- Does the xxxAsync method **just** run in a different thread, and is it the
  same if I run it's equivalent method in a new thread?
- Why would I use `SendTo()` if my socket is already connected to a
  specified endPoint?
- Are these methods practical for both connection oriented and connectionless
  communication?

Comment: Please read [ask] and share your research. All of those questions have been asked before.

Comment: For your async question, you might want to read [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) by Stephen Cleary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you know that the Async versions on these methods are simply non-blocking methods of sending/receiving data.

As for the SendTo and ReceiveFrom, it's just TCP vs UDP.

Use SendTo/ReceiveFrom if you are using UDP and don't care if all packets make it. While Send and Receive is TCP and will make sure all packets reach the end point correctly.

As for being practical, everything I have read is if you want to communicate with a client/server, Sockets are reliable and commonly used.

Comment: Thank you for at least trying to explain without being rude